# SwiftUI ScrollView content height

Tags: xcode, swiftui, geometryreader

I have a problem trying to determine the height of a view inside a ScrollView

```
struct ContentView: View {    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
             GeometryReader { geometry in
                   VStack{
                        ForEach(0..<90) { index in
                             Text("test \(geometry.size.height)")
                        }
                   }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

geometry.size.height is always 10.000.

how can i correct this unexpected result?

Thanks so much!

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: 90 line of text >450 ... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're going with this.

`GeometryReader` reads the size offered to the view, not the size of the view.  You can find out how big the view is by putting a `GeometryReader` in an `.overlay` of the `VStack`, because by the time the overlay is created, the size of the `VStack` will have been established and that size will be offered to the overlay.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
           VStack{
                ForEach(0..<90) { index in
                     Text("test 000000000000")
                         .opacity(0)
                }
           }
           .overlay(
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(0..<90) { index in
                            Text("test \(geometry.size.height)")
                        }
                    }
                }
           )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mofawaw, the OP indicated in the comments above that they expected 90 lines of  text >450 which is why the view is repeated in the `.overlay`.